# Please explain the behaviour of this emacs feature. (Lisp Interaction mode, truncate long lines)

Tags: help, emacs-lisp-mode

Sometimes when a function or variable outputs a very long line, it ends with `...)`. When the cursor is on that line and I press `return`, the line gets longer (probably expanded). I guess this is some sort of folding.

How is this feature called? How can I disable it? How can I use it? How can I split this line into two lines?

How to reproduce:

1. start emacs with: `emacs -Q`
2. load `proced` to create that variable for my example: `M-x proced`
3. switch to `*scratch*` buffer
4. enter `proced-grammar-alist` and press `C-j`
5. then you have that long line with this behaviour.

Edit: changed the title and tags to reflect the topic (after knowing the answer).

Comment: It calls the function `elisp-last-sexp-toggle-display`

Comment: You can also do that with `Mouse-2` (the middle mouse bouton). The function has "Toggle between abbreviated and unabbreviated printed representations." as its docstring.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the ellipsis at the end of some output?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-some-output)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The binding `C-j` runs the command `eval-print-last-sexp`. Use `C-h k C-j` to describe the key binding and see the documentation for the corresponding command. In that doc you'll see some relevant information:

> Normally, this function truncates long output according to the value
>   of the variables ‘eval-expression-print-length’ and
>   ‘eval-expression-print-level’.  With a prefix argument of zero,
>   however, there is no such truncation.

This explains where the `...` is coming from and provides some pointers on how you might customize this behavior or skip it with a prefix argument.

So: If you never want large eval results truncated, you could customize `eval-expression-print-length` and set it to nil or some large value. Or you can use a 0 prefix (i.e. `C-0 C-j`) to eval and get the full result. Either way the non-truncated result will not have the special binding for RET and can be edited normally.

Use the same approach (`C-h k RET`) on a truncated result to learn that RET in that context will call `elisp-last-sexp-toggle-display`. Note that this binding only exists on the original truncated result -- if you expand the result and copy it somewhere else it becomes "regular" text with no magic RET behavior.

Comment: setting 'eval-expression-print-length' does not seem to disable this, but setting 'eval-expression-print-level' helps to disable this feature.