# What is the meaning of the ellipsis at the end of some output?

Tags: print

When I do a `C-j` ie `eval-print-last-sexp` on an expression such as `(copy-tree package-activated-list)`

the output as an ellipsis at the end as shown below

`(ac-ispell auto-complete popup ace-jump-helm-line helm helm-core async popup async avy ace-link avy ...)`

What is the meaning of the ellipsis?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Please explain the behaviour of this emacs feature. (Lisp Interaction mode, truncate long lines)](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33171/please-explain-the-behaviour-of-this-emacs-feature-lisp-interaction-mode-trun)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`...` = truncated = abbreviated = ellipsis

See  `eval-expression-print-level` and `eval-expression-print-length`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html

See also `print-length` and `print-level`:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Variables.html

Comment: When I use `C-j` the output is truncated even when though `print-level` and `print-length` are both `nil`. Is there somethiing else affecting the length of `C-j` output?

Comment: `C-j` is bound to `electric-newline-and-maybe-indent` in `fundamental-mode` in Emacs 25.2.1 built `--with-ns`.  The variables `print-level` and `print-length` are for different circumstances than `eval-expression-print-level` and `eval-expression-print-length`.