# Working with printed macro expansions

Tags: elisp-macros, print, pretty-print

I am trying to write a macro.  I have read the manual and learned about [`macroexpand`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html).  However, when I use it, I find the expansion difficult to read and work with.

How can I expand a macro in a readable, workable format?

Let me illustrate.

If I simply call `macroexpand`, the result is echoed in the minibuffer.  When the expansion is large, the echo is all scrunched up:

```lisp
(macroexpand '(with-temp-file (make-temp-file "test-file")))
```

[image]

I can go to `*Messages*` with `C-h e`, copy and paste it back into `*scratch*`, and then format it.  But clearly that gets tiresome.

To save on the copy/paste, I have tried using `eval-last-sexp` with a universal argument, `C-u C-x C-e`.  This indeed prints the output to the buffer...but it's in some weird interactive state that I cannot edit.  Pressing `RET` causes it to alternate between an abbreviated and expanded form:

Abbreviated (expressions contain ellipses):
[image]

Expanded (Placing point before the expansion and pressing `RET` causes the ellipses to expand and not insert a line break):
[image]

After calling `macroexpand`, `C-h k RET` shows that `elisp-last-sexp-toggle-display` is now the binding for `RET`.

All of this implies some kind of workflow.  However, the documentation for [`macroexpand`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Expansion.html) describes none of this behavior.  The source code is not distributed with my version of Emacs (Emacs 26.3 for Windows).  Scouring the web has found no meaningful explanation of how to work with macro expansions.

Comment: In Lisp Interaction Mode, `C-j` evaluates the expression before point (it is bound to `eval-print-last-sexp`). The result is printed in the buffer. Does that make things a bit easier?

Comment: Thank.  Yes, but only marginally.  It places the result on a newline.  However, the ellipsis behavior is still there.

Comment: What NickD said. Expand the ellipsis mark the region of the result and call Edit -> Text Properties -> Remove Text Properties. If you don't want to use the menu bar you can call `M-x facemenu-remove-all` to remove the fancy text properties.

Comment: More than being about macros your question is about the printing behavior of complex lists. See https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/34413/5223 Also in the link of macrexpand you gave,  below is macroexpand-1. Try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is really more about printing Lisp sexps (including results of evaluation) than it is about macro expansion, per se. It's just that macro expansion typically results in a large Lisp sexp that can be difficult to work with or read, especially if parts of it are elided (`...`).

I use **`pp-eval-last-sexp`**, which I bind to **`C-x C-e`**. (With `C-u` it inserts the result at point, like `eval-last-sexp`.)

You've pointed out some difficulties with this. But try the version of it you get with library [**PP+**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PpPlus) ([**`pp+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/pp%2b.el)).

It respects user options **`pp-eval-expression-print-length`**,
**`pp-eval-expression-print-level`**, and **`pp-max-tooltip-size`**.  The first two are similar to but separate from the standard options with the same names but without prefix `pp-`.  So you can have separate values for pretty printing and non-pretty printing.

I also bind **`M-:`** to **`pp-eval-expression`**, instead of `eval-expression`.

Both of these commands also let you use **`M-0`** to toggle between using a tooltip for the result (when it is no larger than `pp-max-tooltip-size`) and the usual handling (echo area or insertion in current buffer).

(The commands also respect option `eval-expression-debug-on-error`.)