# What is org-capture trying to write to my init.el file?

Tags: org-capture

My init.el is symlinked by NixOS, so that means it's write protected.

For some reason, after org-capture, Emacs tries to write to this file.

I'm not sure I understand what it's trying to write?;)

Emacs also truncates this backtrace and shows three elipsis. How can I prevent that and show the entire backtrace?;)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Attempt to save to a file that you aren’t allowed ...")
  error("Attempt to save to a file that you aren't allowed ...")
  basic-save-buffer-2()
  basic-save-buffer-1()
  basic-save-buffer(nil)
  save-buffer()
  #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_126>(#<buffer 4kwdwkndp0pjq45018phykzmgl2vd1cc-hm_home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.el>)
  map-y-or-n-p(#f(compiled-function (buffer) #<bytecode -0x166b668bec870ccf>) #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_126> (#<buffer capture.org> #<buffer 4kwdwkndp0pjq45018phykzmgl2vd1cc-hm_home.dot.emacs.dot.d.emacsen.el>) ("buffer" "buffers" "save") ((18 #f(compiled-function (buf) #<bytecode 0x19b5453ef578904>) "view this buffer") (6 #f(compiled-function (buf) #<bytecode -0x14d254c4619ebb64>) "view this buffer and quit") (100 #f(compiled-function (buf) #<bytecode -0x109e95b8987dc548>) "view changes in this buffer")))
  save-some-buffers(:no-prompt #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_28>)
  apply(save-some-buffers (:no-prompt #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_28>))
  timer-event-handler([t 0 5 0 :repeat save-some-buffers (:no-prompt #<subr F616e6f6e796d6f75732d6c616d626461_anonymous_lambda_28>) idle 0 nil])
  read-from-minibuffer(#("File 4kwdwkndp0pjq45018phykzmgl2vd1cc-hm_home.dot...." 114 115 (face help-key-binding font-lock-face help-key-binding) 119 120 (face help-key-binding font-lock-face help-key-binding)) nil (keymap (keymap (escape . abort-recursive-edit) (remap keymap (quit . abort-recursive-edit) (exit-prefix . abort-recursive-edit) (exit . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (scroll-other-window-down . minibuffer-scroll-other-window-down) (scroll-other-window . minibuffer-scroll-other-window) (scroll-down . minibuffer-scroll-down-command) (scroll-up . minibuffer-scroll-up-command) (recenter . minibuffer-recenter-top-bottom) (self-insert-command . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (ignore . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (delete-and-edit . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (edit-replacement . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (edit . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (undo-all . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (undo . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (backup . y-or-n-p-insert-other) (skip . y-or-n-p-insert-n) (automatic . y-or-n-p-insert-y) (act-and-exit . y-or-n-p-insert-y) (act-and-show . y-or-n-p-insert-y) (act . y-or-n-p-insert-y)) keymap (18 . helm-minibuffer-history) (menu-bar keymap (minibuf "Minibuf" keymap (previous menu-item "Previous History Item" previous-history-element :help "Put previous minibuffer history element in the min...") (next menu-item "Next History Item" next-history-element :help "Put next minibuffer history element in the minibuf...") (isearch-backward menu-item "Isearch History Backward" isearch-backward :help "Incrementally search minibuffer history backward") (isearch-forward menu-item "Isearch History Forward" isearch-forward :help "Incrementally search minibuffer history forward") (return menu-item "Enter" exit-minibuffer :key-sequence "\15" :help "Terminate input and exit minibuffer") (quit menu-item "Quit" abort-recursive-edit :help "Abort input and exit minibuffer") "Minibuf")) (24 keymap (down . minibuffer-complete-defaults) (up . minibuffer-complete-history)) (13 . exit-minibuffer) (10 . exit-minibuffer) (7 . minibuffer-keyboard-quit) (C-tab . file-cache-minibuffer-complete) (9 . self-insert-command) (XF86Back . previous-history-element) (up . previous-line-or-history-element) (prior . previous-history-element) (XF86Forward . next-history-element) (down . next-line-or-history-element) (next . next-history-element) (27 keymap (60 . minibuffer-beginning-of-buffer) (114 . previous-matching-history-element) (115 . next-matching-history-element) (112 . previous-history-element) (110 . next-history-element))) keymap (escape . exit-prefix) (M-prior . scroll-other-window-down) (M-next . scroll-other-window) (prior . scroll-down) (next . scroll-up) (27 keymap (33554454 . scroll-other-window-down) (22 . scroll-other-window) (118 . scroll-down)) (22 . scroll-up) (29 . quit) (7 . quit) (63 . help) (help . help) (f1 . help) (8 . help) (85 . undo-all) (117 . undo) (94 . backup) (33 . automatic) (12 . recenter) (23 . delete-and-edit) (18 . edit) (46 . act-and-exit) (return . exit) (13 . exit) (113 . exit) (44 . act-and-show) (69 . edit-replacement-exact-case) (101 . edit-replacement) (78 . skip) (89 . act) (110 . skip) (121 . act) (backspace . skip) (delete . skip) (127 . skip) (32 . act)) nil t)
  yes-or-no-p("File 4kwdwkndp0pjq45018phykzmgl2vd1cc-hm_home.dot....")
  basic-save-buffer-2()
  basic-save-buffer-1()
  basic-save-buffer(nil)
  save-buffer()
  custom-save-all()
  customize-save-variable(bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file "~/agenda/bookmark.txt")
  bookmark-save()
  bmkp-maybe-save-bookmarks()
  bookmark-store("org-capture-last-stored" ((annotation) (tags) (filename . "/home/b0ef/agenda/capture.org") (handler . org-bookmark-heading-jump) (id . "c878d848-d811-46c0-9ce4-d8638a23d8ca") (outline-path "WT")) nil nil t)
  bookmark-set("org-capture-last-stored")
  org-capture-store-last-position()
  org-capture-finalize(nil)
  funcall-interactively(org-capture-finalize nil)
  command-execute(org-capture-finalize)
```

Comment: See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55774/working-with-printed-macro-expansions for getting rid of the ellipses.

Comment: Just as an FYI: `org-capture` sets a bookmark: `org-capture-last-stored` (`org-refile` also sets a bookmark: `org-refile-last-stored`). You can use them to jump to the last note you captured (or the last heading you refiled). After a capture or a refile, you can list the bookmarks with `C-x r l` and jump to the last capture by pressing `RET` on the appropriate bookmark.

Comment: thanks, org-capture-goto-last-stored was a missing part of my puzzle;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is read the stack trace.

```
  …
  customize-save-variable(bmkp-last-as-first-bookmark-file "~/agenda/bookmark.txt")
  bookmark-save()
  bmkp-maybe-save-bookmarks()
  bookmark-store("org-capture-last-stored" ((annotation) (tags) (filename . "/home/b0ef/agenda/capture.org") (handler . org-bookmark-heading-jump) (id . "c878d848-d811-46c0-9ce4-d8638a23d8ca") (outline-path "WT")) nil nil t)
  bookmark-set("org-capture-last-stored")
  …
```

As you can see, it set a bookmark and then saved your bookmarks. Bookmarks are saved in a customizable variable, and your customizable variables are stored in your init file.

You can change what file is used to store customizable variables by setting the variable `custom-file`. For example:

```lisp
(setq custom-file (concat dotfiles-dir "custom.el"))
```

Comment: It is probably a good idea to have a separate customization file instead of saving customizations in your init file. Add `
(setq custom-file "/path/to/customize.el")
(load-file custom-file)` to your init file and make sure that `customize.el` is somewhere where Emacs can save to.

Comment: I already had this code, but it was somehow being blocked in init.el for other reasons;) thanks