# Exclude org_archive files from agenda

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

In `~/.emacs/init.el` i have:

```
(setq org-agenda-files (list "~/org"))
```

Most of the .org files in that directory have associated .org_archive files with a long history of archived TODO tasks.

When I run org-agenda, it collects any TODO item in the .org_archive files.

Is there a regex type solution to exclude files ending in `.org_archive`? I've previously identified individual files to include in the agenda view but that's getting a little cumbersome.

The value of `org-agenda-file-regexp` is:

```
"\\`[^.].*\\.org\\'"
```

Comment: There is `org-agenda-file-regexp` but its default setting should not allow matching `foo.org_archive` files anyway. What is the value of that variable in your setup? Please edit the question and add that information.

Comment: hmm added, The value looks as though it should exclude things ending in .org_archive but I recompiled the agenda and it definitely includes items from archive files. I noticed that it seems like it's only items that I set the Style property to habit. If that property is commented out they no longer appear in the agenda.

Comment: What does `(org-agenda-files)` return? You can evaluate that by entering it in your `*scratch*` buffer and pressing `C-j`. The return value should be a list of all the agenda files. Does it include any `.org_archive` files?

Comment: I don't know what a Style property does: AFAICT, it's not special to Org mode at all. Are you using some third-party package that uses that?

Comment: just from the org habits feature https://orgmode.org/manual/Tracking-your-habits.html. Org-agenda-files doesn't list any archive files. it ends with ` ...)` though so maybe the list continues?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's actually spelled STYLE in the code, which is why I didn't find it at first (note to future self: use `grep -i`). The ellipsis does indeed mean there is more: see https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-some-output for some settings that will allow you to see the whole thing.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of `org-agenda-archive-mode`. In my case it was set to true in my init.el.

```
(setq org-agenda-archives-mode t)
```

Setting it to `nil` (the default) makes it so that archived items are not included in the agenda.

The docstring of the variable says:

> Non-nil means the agenda will include archived items.
>   If this is the symbol ‘trees’, trees in the selected agenda scope
>   that are marked with the ARCHIVE tag will be included anyway.  When this is
>   t, also all archive files associated with the current selection of agenda
>   files will be included.

Comment: BTW, [you can accept your own answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: oh yeah, it always makes me wait a couple hours or something so I forget