# How can I get a complete backtrace?

Tags: debug, backtrace

I've gotten some code that was supposed to give me a complete backtrace

```
(setq debug-ignored-errors (remove 'args-out-of-range debug-ignored-errors))
```

, but I still see it shortened with three dots

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "The connected server(s) does not support method te...")
  error("The connected server(s) does not support method %s..." "textDocument/references")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the ellipsis at the end of some output?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-some-output)