# How can I disable ellipsis in backtraces?

Tags: debug-on-error

I have these lines:

```
;default 12
(setq eval-expression-print-length 0)
;default 4
(setq eval-expression-print-level 0)

(setq backtrace-verbose t)
(setq debugger-args '("--no-debugger-ellipsis"))
```

, but I'm still seeing this:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not find package openai. Updating recipe rep...")
  error("Could not find package %S. Updating recipe reposit..." openai (org-elpa melpa gnu-elpa-mirror nongnu-elpa el-get emacsmirror-mirror))
```

Comment: The doc string of both variables says: `A value of nil means no limit.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a complete backtrace?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79186/how-can-i-get-a-complete-backtrace)