# How can I prevent truncation when using which key?

Tags: which-key

When using which key, how can I see the whole function name and prevent it from being truncated.

I've searched a bit on this and I'm just confused;). I'm not sure if this is a bug or a simple setting.

In the screenshot here, the function is truncated with "..."

[image]

I also tried that suggestion:

```
(setq print-length 30)
(setq print-level 30)

(setq eval-expression-print-level 30)
(setq eval-expression-print-length 30)
```

, but that didnt't affect the output

Comment: What does your `which-key` UI look like?  Perhaps better to upload a screenshot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of the ellipsis at the end of some output?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34413/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-ellipsis-at-the-end-of-some-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize `which-key-max-description-length`. The doc string says:

```
which-key-max-description-length is a variable defined in ‘which-key.el’.

Its value is 27

Truncate the description of keys to this length.
Also adds "..". If nil, disable any truncation.
```